# Sqlalchemy "Packet sequence number wrong" despite using scoped_session

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am using Flask with Sqlalchemy, and since switching from mysqldb to pymysql, I am getting this error:
`InternalError('(pymysql.err.InternalError) Packet sequence number wrong - got 29 expected 1')` (numbers vary depending on query)

This error is quite rare (around 1 in 100), and the reason I am switching to pymysql from mysqldb is because mysqldb kept creating utf8 decoding errors *at a somewhat similar rate*. Is it possible I am still getting errors because of this, and pymysql is interpreting the "invalid start byte" as an "invalid packet sequence" error, from the same problem further downstream?

As the title says, I already implemented scoped_session and it does not resolve the issue. Maybe I am doing something wrong?

engine_creation.py

```
def create_engine(db="")
    engine = sqlalchemy_package.create_engine(
        'mysql+pymysql://' + acc + ':' + pw + '@'
        + host + ':' + port + '/' + db + '?charset=utf8mb4',
        pool_recycle=3600, pool_size=25, max_overflow=5)
```

query_execution.py

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
session_factory = sessionmaker(autocommit=True)
def execute_query(engine, query, parameters=None):
    session_factory.configure(bind=engine)
    my_session = scoped_session(session_factory)
    result = my_session.execute(query, parameters)  # noqa
    return result
```

some_resource.py

```
from engine_creation import create_engine
from query_execution import execute_query
engine = create_engine(db=some_db)
result_proxy = execute_query(engine, query, parameters)
```

Changing +pymysql to +mysqldb will work exactly the same, but the "packet sequence" error will change to `UnicodeDecodeError('utf-8', b'\xf6', 8, 9, 'invalid start byte')` . Has anyone heard of this before? I am still trying to debug why I am getting a UnicodeDecodeError, and if switching to a different dialect is producing a different error - or the same error, expressed differently.

Code worked fine without scoped_session and it seems superfluous if it doesnt fix the Packet sequence error. Sorry if this seems like multiple questions at once, but my gut feeling tells me these problems are related.

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] that produces the error with some certainty?

Comment: That is the minimal code required. All you need is to select a varchar field such as "interférence" which produces the UTF-8 decoding error. Swapping the dialect will change the error, as explained. Unfortunately, this error is inconsistent, and that is part of the problem. I cannot force it to happen every time. I will add some specifics about the database used.

Comment: This is not reproducible though, which in case of a bug like this is paramount. Put another way, even if I take your snippets, I do not know how to run the code in a way that will produce the error with some propability.

Comment: I know & I expected this to be extremely hard to reproduce. Thats why my main focus was on why I am getting the "Packet sequence error" despite having correctly implemented scoped_sessions (and asking if I did). If there is no error in the code I provided, the error should (or must) be related to the utf-8 decoding error, misinterpreted by pymysql. For anyone in the future having similar problems. Upgrading to MariaDB 10.5 solved the issue, apparently it is caused by MySQL 5.7. Unfortunately google lead me to believe this error is always caused by unscoped sessions and thread safety in flask.

Comment: Regarding scoped sessions, if you build the registry every time you execute, it's not doing much :). Scoped session is a registry that makes it easier to tie the session's lifetime to that of something else, for example a thread.

Comment: If my scoped_session code was wrong you should have told me before I ripped it out of my codebase. Thanks for your consideration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As expected, this error is not related to flask, sqlalchemy or unscoped sessions. As I see it, it is an error caused by MySQL 5.7 interacting with the pymysql dialect which throws the "Packet Sequence error", when its actually an UTF-8 issue.

In any case, upgrading to MariaDB 10.5 solved this issue. Implementing scoped_sessions was not necessary.